# Occasional fail from json request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to build something that iterates through each item in a list, gets a product sku, includes that sku in a jsonp request hoping for an object back.  I have it where it does all these things but with occasional failure.

So the example of the script that is looping through the list elements, grabbing the class to get the proper id #, and then sending the request out :

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('ul.products-grid li a.product-image img').each(function(index){
        var prodId = $j(this).attr('class').match(/[\d]+$/),
            s7jsonReqUrl = '/is/image/z/' + prodId + '/?req=imageset,json';
        $j.ajax({
                 url: s7jsonReqUrl,                         
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      jsonp: 'true',
                      jsonpCallback: 's7jsonResponse',
                      success: function(response)
                      {                
                        x = response["IMAGE_SET"];  
                        console.log(x);
                      }, 
                      error: function(data, status)
                      {
                        console.log ( 'error : ' + data + ' : ' + status );
                      }
                 });
              });
            })
```

If I were to take each of those urls and manually paste them in the browsers (those from the s7jsonReqUrl var), they would return the expected json object, even those that fail from the test above.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: you are sending off n requests, all expecting to use the exact same jsonp callback. that's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're reaching a race condition due to jQuery repeatedly defining and redefining the s7jsonResponse.

I would do this the non-jquery way since the callback parameter isn't dynamic..

```
window.s7jsonResponse = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};

var sendForJSON = function (prodId) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = '/is/image/z/' + prodId + '/?req=imageset,json';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
};
```

now just use `sendForJSON` to get data.

```
.each(function(){
    var prodId = $j(this).attr('class').match(/[\d]+$/);
    sendForJSON(prodId);
})
```

should probably also add logic to remove the script tags after a response is received.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! That helps a lot.  I already am stuck again and thought I would throw it in here to see if you have any ideas (might have to make yet another SO post though).  So I can grab the variable I want now for each item in that list. Hurray! Now I need to append that var (that came from the json response) after each item that was originally iterated over in the .each.  I am getting lost.. so if I pass another parameter of the class name to target where that append will go, how would I execute that?  From the window.s7jsonResponse function??  Thanks for any more help or ideas.

Comment: you could extract the prodId from the returned data, then use that to get the original element

Comment: Cool yes I am working through a similar idea.. sometimes asking the question helps me think things through.  Thanks again for your help!!